# How to handle to input stream in Pentaho with script steps?

Tags: pentaho

1. How many different kind of steps in Pentaho can accept more than one input stream, such as "Merge Join", "Stream Look up"?
2. What's the typical user scenario of them?
3. Any script related steps can accept more than one stream as input, like javascript or UDJC? e.g. use one stream as data source, another as filter condition?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

All the steps under "Joins" and "Lookup", joins just like table join, lookup is to using one stream as source dataset another as "translate" dictionary, this is what I know

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 3 questions as below:

1. All the Steps available in "Joins" and "Lookup" section will accept two streams. *(i haven't tried with 3 streams)* Some filter steps like Java Filter will also accept more than one stream.
2. Typical use scenario is to get data from one or more streams and to work on your business logic. There is no specific example i can explain at the moment.
3. As per my knowledge, you cannot use more than one stream in JavaScript Step. You might get an error like 
   [image]

I am trying to stream two columns of different names. Input 1 has column "a" and Input 2 has column "b".

[image]

You can ignore this error if you can make both the input stream columns to the same name.

Hope this help :)